# Trying to hide an object / create a fold effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a rather unique effect. It's actually not that complicated, what I'm trying to do is build an experimental site, which I have already done. I just can't seem to figure out how to go about doing the final step.

So this is my site I'm tinkering with http://www.dig.ital.me/sandbox/about-me/

And what I'm trying to do is collapse the left-side bar that has the text in it : "Made in blah blah blah, etc."  By clicking on the : " Click this to hide this " .

And I've tried going about doing an  anchor link associated with a name link and calling the display:none when that link is clicked. However, it isn't working. So I thought I would try stackoverflow, on how I could about achieving this kind of effect where it collapses, and re-opens again.

```
#hide-option { color:#FFF; width:500px; height:500px; padding-left:170px;}
#hide-option:hover .fixedfooter {
display:none;
cursor:pointer; }
```

Here's a snippet of the hide-option div id. I've exhausted a lot of routes to try and achieve this effect but I cannot seem how to figure it out. I've tried the :onClick class, and nth-child classes, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//  Store the footer as a variable, so we don't have to keep calling jQuery's selector engine
//  It's slower than a tortoise stuck in a traffic jam.
var target = $('.fixedfooter');

//  Every time the hide-option link is clicked
$('#hide-option a').click(function() {

    //  If the left position of the target is 0
    if(parseInt(target.css('left')) == 0) {
        //  Check the target is not animated and, if it is, animate off screen
        !target.is(':animated') && target.animate({left: -751}, 250);
    } else {
        //  Assume it's hidden, and put it back to the start
        !target.is(':animated') && target.animate({left: 0}, 250);
    }

    //  Stop the link being followed
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Hey quick question. I'm not sure whats going on but you have to double click the link at first to close it. Would you know what the reason behind that is? After it's doubled click , it only requires one click after to reactivate / activate.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/), the JavaScript library, will solve it all for you.

```
$("el").bind("onclick",function(){$("el").toggle('slow');});
```

Comment: Hmmm, I tried looking into jQuery. I just added the code above, thanks for the response. I somehow am having trouble getting it to work. So I imported the latest Jquery version and writing <script> your code </script> and linking this as the css #hide-option:onClick .fixedfooter {
 display:none;
 cursor:pointer;
} What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want CSS3 (if you don't care about IE6-8), here's something you could try: http://jsbin.com/isunoz/6/edit

I've commented it as much as possible, I hope it helps :)

What I've done is to use a checkbox input to decide if the sidebar should be shown or not.

By putting the checkbox input element right before the sidebar element (*div.fixedfooter*) and changing your anchor (the arrow) into a label for that checkbox, I'm able to use the *:checked* pseudo class and the *+* selector to target the sibling element (in this case, the sidebar *div.fixedfooter*). If the checkbox is checked, the sidebar is moved out of the screen and if it's not checked, the sidebar is shown (*left: 0*).

For the animation I've used some css3 transition (*transition: left .4s ease*) :)

Comment: For Paper fold effects see this nice demo app, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/paperfold-css/launch